# Excel VBA: Performing a function to overwrite contents of cells, using contents of those same cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a simple operation on a column of data in Excel VBA. If a cell in column B starts with a letter *before* 'N', nothing happens to the cell. If the cell starts with a letter 'N' or later (in the alphabet), it replaces the cell contents with "!!!!!".

Here is my code that correctly applies this to *another* column:

```
Range("C1", Range("C1").End(xlDown)).Value = "=IF(LEFT(A1,1)<""N"",B1,""!!!!!"")"
```

This works fine, and makes column C contain the correct output. However, in order to replace column B, I then need to convert column C to literal values, and then delete all of column B.

These extra steps seem a little unnecessary and cumbersome. Is there a way of applying the formula straight over column B, without needing to assign a the values to a separate column and then destroying the original column B?

Comment: You can place formula in B, and then "paste" the value back to B itself.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your point - tested this - seemingly works fine. Maybe you should provide some data example.

Comment: Your code sets this if formular into col C, whereby the formula will reflect eighter the value of col B or "!!!!" - if you want to change B directly, you can do what the formula does in vba, then replace the values of col B.

Comment: This works - I was just looking for a solution that is more efficient :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set myRng to whatever amount of rows you need. It doesn't seem to work with a complete column.

```
Sub CaptainProgsSub()

Dim myRng As Range, cell As Range
Set myRng = Range("B1:B100")

For Each cell In myRng
    If Left(Range("B" & cell.row), 1) > "N" Then Range("B" & cell.row) = "!!!!!"
Next cell

End Sub
```